# How to interpret ARMA subsets in R (for more complex timeseries models)?

Tags: r, time-series, subset, moving-average, autoregressive-models

I am working with a timeseries dataset in R. I have to propose several models, one of which has to come from using armasubsets (I know there are functions such as auto.arima(), but I still have to leverage this plot). How would you interpret this arma subsets plot in R?[image: arma subsets plot]

I was thinking specifically of the fifth row down, because it's BIC value is only ten higher, and although we want to minimize BIC, I thought this small difference would be justified by the fact the fifth row from the top is significantly simpler than the other potential models specified by this plot. Therefore, how would I interpret something with AR components at lag 5, 11, and 12, and an MA component at lag 1.

How does this interpretation change for something like this plot: [image: arma subsets plot 2] I was thinking of the 5th row down as well with a BIC value of -220.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the lags with the arima function using order and seasonal. p is AR, d is differencing, and q is MA.

```
arima(x, order = c(p, d, q),
      seasonal = list(order = c(p, d, q)
```

You could also use `auto.arima()` from the forecast package to have R figure out the components for you.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of using that function as well. I am not sure however, how would I specify the parameters I provided in my question? As a recap, lags 10, 11, and 12 in the AR component are significant, so how do I specifically make sure that those lags are considered even if I set p = 3? Additionally, both 5 and 12 are significant in the MA part of the model, so how do I specifically make sure those lags are considered while other ones are not? You also did not include the period input which I believe is necessary to specify for the seasonal part of the model.

Comment: @JaneSully I do not think you can skip AR terms. Also, I have not used arima, i've only used functions from forecast, but I believe it can get the period from the ts object.

Comment: @JaneSully since you want to use BIC to choose the components just run auto.arima and add ic = "BIC" to the function. That will give you what you're looking for.

Comment: @JaneSully Is your seasonal period 5? That will give you a AR parameter 5 spots away without including any intermediate lags.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the auto.arima() function. I think it is a useful tool, but definitely does not fit the data as expected (as there is still some sort of trend). Will have to play around more!

Comment: @JaneSully this post might help for understanding the trend. http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arima-trends/

Answer (score 0):

You mention that "this small difference would be justified by the fact the fifth row from the top is significantly simpler than the other potential models specified by this plot."

The BIC already accounts for simplicity by penalising complex models, so choosing a simpler model with a lower BIC is effectively weighting simplicity twice.

The table indicates that AR(1),AR(2),AR(3),AR(4),AR(8) and MA(3),MA(8) and MA(12) are all possible models.

Your set of possible models is a combination of these ARMA values: 
{ARMA(1,3),ARMA(1,8),ARMA(1,12),ARMA(2,3),ARMA(2,8),ARMA(2,12),ARMA(3,3),
ARMA(3,8),ARMA(3,12),ARMA(4,3),ARMA(4,8),ARMA(4,12),ARMA(8,3),ARMA(8,8),ARMA(8,12)}

Most of those will not be suitable, as this only indicates possible models. Test the coefficients of each of these models and exclude any where not all coefficients are significant. Then you can run your residuals tests, etc, on the remaining models.